# How do I get total number of columns received in RestAPI response?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, redux

[image: Example Response From RestAPI]

**This Is How My Current Parameter Input Looks Like:**

```
value={data?.body?.marketState}
```

**I want to return no. of columns in "*marketState*".**

eg.

```
4
```

Comment: data?.body?.marketState.length

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply access the `.length` property on the array

`value={data?.body?.marketState?.length}`

For more info about `.length`:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

For more information about JavaScript arrays in general:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array